# can not insert news application because of different language codes for japanese

Tags: web-application

I can't insert the news application because of the different language code.
When creating a new information to the news app I can select only "jp-jp" for Japanese, but when I insert the app onto a page, an error appears with the message "no news found. please check that you have published at least one item with the language code "ja-jp" "
Can you help?

Comment: What news app are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This message occurs when you don't have any news with the language code of your current web site.

For example, if your web site is in japanese you must have at least one item with the "jp-jp" language code.

[Corporate News App for SharePoint 2013](http://corporatenewsapp.codeplex.com/workitem/1331)